# Add watermark in existing video on mobile platforms using xamarin froms

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

`Add watermark in existing video on mobile platforms using xamarin froms` 
'I tried to use FFMpeg but it's nuget package for android has not been updated since 2017 and I was unable to add that nuget package in my Xamarin Android project.'

```
public async Task AddWatermarkToVideo(NSUrl videoFilePath, NSUrl outputFilePath)
{
    string step = "1";
    try
    {
        `here i get video url`
        var videoAsset = AVUrlAsset.FromUrl(videoFilePath) as AVUrlAsset;
        
        `I need to herer add watermark`
        `I need to herer add trak get`
        AVMutableComposition mixComposition = AVMutableComposition.Create();
        var compositionVideoTracks = mixComposition.AddMutableTrack(AVMediaType.Video, 0);
        AVAssetTrack clipVideoTrack = videoAsset.TracksWithMediaType(AVMediaType.Video)[0];
        var compositionAudioTrack = mixComposition.AddMutableTrack(AVMediaType.Audio, 0);
        AVAssetTrack clipAudioTrack = videoAsset.TracksWithMediaType(AVMediaType.Audio)[0];
            
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessagingCenter.Send<string>("Fail : " + "Test Excep "+ step +" " + ex.Message, "VideoExportError");
    }

}
```